# How to clear a layer in Krita? delete not working half the time

Tags: krita

I don't understand. In Krita, if I make a new project and work on it then want to clear a layer, I simply hit delete once and it's done. But all my existing projects I hit delete on, either only work for certain layers and things or it doesn't do anything at all.

Like text wasn't clearing from the layer. I had to hand-select and delete it.

What is going on and how do I get it to clear the layer entirely on button press?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently just select the layer and hit delete do not work on **vector layers**. The less annoying thing to do is to use **select shapes tool** to draw a selection area over everything and hit delete.